# How can I pass a message from JMeter to Sonic ESB?

Tags: jms, jmeter, message-queue, sonicmq

I am trying to use the point-to-point functionality of JMeter to test Sonic ESB.

I developed a service in Sonic ESB (a very simple service which has only one prototype step). I wanted to pass a message from JMeter to the service which I developed in Sonic ESB and get a response back.

I have an input Queue named Sample.Q1.

I am really confused about how to link JMeter and Sonic ESB.

I followed the following link in creating the jmeter point-to-point. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html

Please tell me how to provide authentication details also (i.e user name and password).

Comment: Show what you tried and which errors you are getting

Comment: I was wondering why are you not using the JMS Test client

Answer (score 0):

Configure the JMS Point-to-Point Sampler with Sonic information.

Have you configured your prototype Service with a replyTo endpoint in the output?
You can also disable the authentication or use JMS properties.